# Issues getting a show hide function to work right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have three titles acting as buttons. Button 1, 2 and 3. On page load, I am wanting the button 1 section to show, but then if someone would click on button 2 or 3 for the previous button description to hide and for the new one to appear in its place.

So far I cannot get this to work. I added `display: none;` to the general class, but I as I said, I want the first one to display on page load.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('#big-three-names').click(function() {
   var thisDescription = $('.big-three-info', $(this));
   $('.big-three-info').not(thisDescription).hide().parent().removeClass('closed');
   thisDescription.slideToggle(500).parent().toggleClass('closed');
 });
```

```css
.big-three {
 margin: 75px 7.5% 25px 7.5%;
 height: 900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#big-three-title {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
}
#big-three-description {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
#big-three-names-out {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 50px 0;
}
.big-three-names {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
 width: 33.05%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.big-three-names:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 color: #FFF;
}
.big-three-info {
 margin: 50px 20%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 550px;
  display: none;
}
#big-three-info-title { 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 100px 0 25px 50px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
#big-three-info-description { 
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="big-three-out">
  <div class="big-three">
   <div id="big-three-title">The "Big Three"</div>
   <div id="big-three-description">fdmsnfdnofnkosjafnndsa.</div>
   <div id="big-three-names-out">
    <div class="big-three-names">1</div><div class="big-three-names">2</div><div class="big-three-names">3</div>
    <div class="big-three-info">
     <div id="big-three-info-title">
      1
     </div>
     <div id="big-three-info-description">
      Description for 1.
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="big-three-info">
     <div id="big-three-info-title">
      2
     </div>
     <div id="big-three-info-description">
      Description for 2.
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="big-three-info">
     <div id="big-three-info-title">
      3
     </div>
     <div id="big-three-info-description">
      Description for 3.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following way using JQuery. Get html text of selected button and display div using `.eq()` of JQuery.

Display first using `$('.big-three-info').eq(0).css("display", "block");` on page load.

```js
$('.big-three-names').click(function() {
    var i = $( this ).html();
    $('.big-three-info').css("display", "none")
    $('.big-three-info').eq(i-1).css("display", "block");
  });

$('.big-three-info').eq(0).css("display", "block");
```

```css
.big-three {
 margin: 75px 7.5% 25px 7.5%;
 height: 900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#big-three-title {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
}
#big-three-description {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
#big-three-names-out {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 50px 0;
}
.big-three-names {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
 width: 33.05%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.big-three-names:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 color: #FFF;
}
.big-three-info {
 margin: 50px 20%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 550px;
  display: none;
}
#big-three-info-title { 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 100px 0 25px 50px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
#big-three-info-description { 
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size: 1em;
}
.show{
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="big-three-out">
  <div class="big-three">
   <div id="big-three-title">The "Big Three"</div>
   <div id="big-three-description">fdmsnfdnofnkosjafnndsa.</div>
   <div id="big-three-names-out">
    <div class="big-three-names">1</div><div class="big-three-names">2</div><div class="big-three-names">3</div>
    <div class="big-three-info">
     <div id="big-three-info-title">
      1
     </div>
     <div id="big-three-info-description">
      Description for 1.
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="big-three-info">
     <div id="big-three-info-title">
      2
     </div>
     <div id="big-three-info-description">
      Description for 2.
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="big-three-info">
     <div id="big-three-info-title">
      3
     </div>
     <div id="big-three-info-description">
      Description for 3.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the first one appear on page load, though?

Comment: Whenever I make this live, if I click any of the options, nothing comes up. Why would it do that?

Comment: Can you give the live link?

Answer (score 1):

1.[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pwqbqyq9/)

2.[Updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pwqbqyq9/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-three-out">
        <div class="big-three">
            <div id="big-three-title">The "Big Three"</div>
            <div id="big-three-description">fdmsnfdnofnkosjafnndsa.</div>
            <div id="big-three-names-out">
                <div class="big-three-names one">1</div><div class="big-three-names two">2</div><div class="big-three-names three">3</div>
                <div class="big-three-info one-sub">
                    <div id="big-three-info-title">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div id="big-three-info-description">
                        Description for 1.
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="big-three-info two-sub">
                    <div id="big-three-info-title">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div id="big-three-info-description">
                        Description for 2.
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="big-three-info three-sub">
                    <div id="big-three-info-title">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div id="big-three-info-description">
                        Description for 3.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.big-three-names').click(function() {


   $(".big-three-info").hide();
   $("."+$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1]+"-sub").show();



    });
```

By the way `big-three-names` is your `class` name and not `ID`

Comment: Is there anyway to make the first one appear on page load, though?

Comment: @Paul : checkouit the second demo .,. i have pasted on top of my answer

Comment: @Paul : all other answers will not work if you change the button value... mine will always work...informing you just in case you need this

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution

```
$('.big-three-info').eq(0).show();//show the first 
$('.big-three-names').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();//getting the index for button
    $('.big-three-info').hide().eq(index).show();//first hide all then show the div with equal index 
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7LLqr79/)